# Is there a way to display date inside a page without using plugins or custom codes?

Tags: front-end, date

Is there a way to display date inside a page or post without using plugins or custom code inside functions.php ? for example like using short codes

Comment: The code for that has to be _somewhere_. Otherwise you have to write the date manually into the post content.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.